# how to make selenium web driver wait for infinite time

Tags: java, selenium

```
public class Ajax_steps {

private String URL = "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/ajax.html";
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;

public void start(){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(URL);           
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".container")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("yes")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("buttoncheck")).click();
    WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.className("radiobutton"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(textElement));

driver.close();

 }
}
```

the above code is working perfectly. But i need a modification like when we declare `new WebDriverWait` with 3 sec . i want it wait  for infinite time...How can i do it...

Comment: Why not simply increase the number of implicit time.  There is no infinite command but waiting 2000000000 might do the trick for you

Comment: i know it but is there any other way..

Comment: Why not just use the maximum long value as a parameter how many seconds it should wait instead of your current 3 seconds? That would be 9223372036854775807 seconds or 292,471,205,753 years. Long enough that our solar system will have stopped existing by then.

Comment: Maybe.  Someone else might know. Typing in the number of implicit is clean and beautiful this way.  Alternatively use explicit which waits until element is visible and you won't get stuck on 20000000000 seconds if element is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change below parameters

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(365, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Instead of doing above you should try either `ExplicitWait` or `FluentWait` .

**FluentWait** : which will pool withing given time weather your element is present or not

```
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

I hope you are looking for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **`Java`** and trying to tweak with the **`WebDriverWait`** constructor parameter by increasing the **`timeOutInSeconds`** parameter, we need to remember that **`Java`** supports primitive data types. So when we mention :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
```

The **`timeOutInSeconds`** parameter can be increased till the highest limit of **`integer`** `Primitive Data Type` i.e. till **`2147483647`**.

If you try to increase the time limit of **`timeOutInSeconds`** beyond that  limit, either the IDE you are using will show **`Compilation Errors`** or during run-time the call to the **`WebDriverWait Constructor`** may return improper results.